# SolidWorks/Inventor/Catia circuit simulation?

Tags: autodesk, solidworks, catia

I use Labcenter Proteus Circuit simulation - you create circuit design, then apply current and see simulation in action - for example leds are blinking, or motor is rotating. If there is microcontroller - say AVR, you just load compiled hex file for it and see simulation live - again, if it was programmed to blink led, and there is one on pin, it will blink, or you can simulate button pressing and see what happens, etc.

Now, I know SolidWorks have SolidWorks Electric, SolidWorks Simulation, SolidWorks CircuitWorks (are those all?), is there any way to have such functionality in it? I mean, if I have added motor to project, then created circuit with avr microcontroller in SolidWorks electrical, is there a way to somehow combine those two, set .hex file for avr and run simulation to see how motor moves? Or Any alternative, how do engineers do such things?

Or even more globally, is it possible in any cad software - AutoDesk Inventor, Comsol Multiphysics or Catia?

thx.

Comment: Perhaps http://engineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @TobiaTesan yes, I also asked there, but as far as I can see, there is not much of views/answers. Also I saw solidworks and katia questions here with answers.

Comment: not a professional tool, but check https://123d.circuits.io/

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves I know this one, but I want this to be exported to solidworks somehow. I can not make magnetic motion tests in 123d, in solidworks (or inventor) I can.

Comment: I flagged to close as off-topic for SO.  You might have better luck on SuperUser.  The engineering site is still in beta and doesn't have a lot of members yet.  Eng-tips.com has a decent cad forum where you might find some advice as well - though I'd rather see an answer on SE as its such a more searchable and useable site.